# Quick check on use of map api (android)

Tags: android, api, dictionary, classpath

When you use the Google map api, it is not part of the Android SDK, and you have to mention it in your manifest xml file.

Do you have to do anything to access the jar file containing the map api code?  Or is that automatically present on the device or emulator, the way the SDK code is?

Do you need put the map api jar file in your class path, either when compiling or when executing?  Or is it kept somewhere where it is already visible, and the requirement of an XML mention is merely to remind you of the licensing issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google APIs will be on the device if the device supports it; no need to include any extra jar files.